# WSL 'Open Linux shell here' doesn't open in the current directory

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

If I right-click on a folder holding shift it does show open Linux shell here.
But if I am in say `D:` drive no matter which folder I am in it will always open the Linux shell starting at `/mnt/d`.

What could be the reason for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Likely something in a startup script is interfering, but let's walk through the troubleshooting.

First, let's check the command that Windows is using when you select "Open Linux shell here".  In PowerShell:

`(Get-ItemProperty -name "(default)" -LiteralPath Registry::HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\WSL\command).'(default)'`

The result should be `wsl.exe --cd "%V"`, and I'm guessing it is.  If not, you can fix that with a registry edit.

But let's try that command from PowerShell as well:

`wsl.exe --cd "D:\some directory"` (where, obviously, some directory is replaced with something that exists on your drive).

I'm also guessing that this will have the same results for you that the right click did - It will end up in D:\ rather than the desired directory.  But if it *does* work, then we'll need to investigate further on why there's a difference with the right-click Open-with command.

So now, let's see if we can make it *work* from the CLI.  Try:

`wsl.exe --cd "D:\some directory" -e bash --noprofile --norc`

I'm hoping that works for you.  That will indicate the problem is something in your `.profile` or `.bashrc` (or another startup script).

If so, see if you can track any startup script customization you've done that might affect the `cd`.  It's possible that the change was made by some installer, as well.  Or perhaps even that some distribution's stock startup scripts are a problem.  You didn't mention which distro you are using, but things work correctly for me on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Yeah man!! . That was so cool!! I fixed it. .bashrc file had a line `cd /mnt/d` .

Comment: I really liked the way you approached this. I want to become good at all this. Is there any book/online courses you recommend? I know these skills cannot be gained directly from a book or course. But the understanding happens over time. Still any recommendations which could improve me in computer science. Thanks a lot

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I have the expected command, and it works for Windows directories properly, but when it is using a folder in WSL, it always goes to the home folder, even when using the `--noprofile --norc` flags

Comment: @mbomb007 By "using a folder in WSL", do you mean that the path is somewhere in `\\wsl$\distroname\...`?

Comment: @Amitwadhwa Apologies for not responding on your question sooner.  And thank you!  Just asking that question shows you have the *desire* to make it happen.  Short answer here - (1) Fail often :-).  Seriously - The more you fail, the more you learn how to identify and more rapidly solve problems in the future.  (2) Outline everything.  Break your notes down into outline form - IMHO, this helps you develop a habit of breaking down problems into their base parts as well.  Happy to discuss further in a [chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231545/902710), if you'd like.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds Yes.

Comment: @mbomb007 - Do you have more than one instance installed and running?  My default distribution name is "Ubuntu", but I also have another instance named "kali" running.  If I do `wsl --cd "\\wsl$\Ubuntu\"` then it correctly goes to the root.  But if I do `wsl --cd "\\wsl$\kali\"`, then it goes to my Ubuntu `$HOME`.  This is expected behavior since my default distro ("Ubuntu") doesn't have access to the "kali" distribution filesystem.  Is there any chance this is what you are seeing?

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds I at one time had a second distro running, but I recently removed it completely. If I run `wsl.exe --cd "K:/home/kali/projects"` in PowerShell, it still goes to `K:/home/kali`. I'm using a mapped network drive, where `K:/` is `\\wsl$`.

Comment: Ah, that probably makes sense then.  That really should be a separate question - "'Open Linux shell here' doesn't work for \\wsl$\ share mapped to a drive letter". The reason is simple - WSL doesn't know about the `K:` drive.  The mapping doesn't exist when WSL starts, so `/mnt/k` isn't created *inside* the instance.  And WSL is smart enough to launch into the correct ext4 folder when you tell it to `--cd` to `\\wsl$`, but it doesn't know about your `K:`->`\\wsl$` mapping.  So it's trying to `cd` to what it thinks is a non-existent drive.  That always results in opening to $HOME instead.