# 'open linux shell here' starts in home directory

Tags: command-line, shell, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have one specific directory (they key is the directory name, see below) on my filesystem where starting the wsl shell will always start me out in the home directory instead. Like so:

```
PS C:\Source\Code\contentmatch.stream> wsl
jjk@pc-name:~$
```

Trying to do the same through the file explorer dialogue option (open Linux shell here) has the same effect.

Behind the hood, the command that actually does this has the same effect as well

```
PS C:\Source\Code\contentmatch.stream> wsl --cd "C:\Source\Code\contentmatch.stream"
jjk@pc-name:~$
```

This does not happen in any other directory. **Renaming this directory to anything else mitigates the issue**. Creating another directory with same name will again trigger the same behaviour.
I can access that directory from the WSL level without any issues.
I've string searched the registry for any references to said string, but nothing there.

After reading this:
[WSL open linux shell here doesn't open in the current directory](https://superuser.com/questions/1619781/wsl-open-linux-shell-here-doesnt-open-in-the-current-directory)
Have tried also this command, but the result was the same:

```
PS C:\Source\Code\contentmatch.stream> wsl --cd "C:\Source\Code\contentmatch.stream" -e bash --noprofile --norc
bash-5.0$ ls
LICENSE  datadump.jsons  efs-utils  error  out  output  packages-microsoft-prod.deb
bash-5.0$ exit
exit
PS C:\Source\Code\contentmatch.stream>
```

It appears to me as if there's some mapping file which redirects or otherwise disables this particular path from starting wsl but having searched far and wide online, I can't identify what that is.

Where do I look for the cause of this behaviour?

Comment: Thanks for reposting over here.  I was going to suggest the `bash --noprofile --norc`, but you found that already.  What distribution are you using?  Here's my result under Ubuntu 20.04:  `wsl --cd "C:\Source\Code\contentmatch.stream" -e bash --noprofile --norc -c pwd` correctly results in `/mnt/c/Source/Code/contentmatch.stream`.  Trying to noodle out a reason why yours is different.

Comment: I'm on ubuntu 20.04 as well.

Comment: Also should mention that I've tried under both PowerShell and PowerShell Core (latest version, 7.1.2, released yesterday).  Both work correctly here.  I'm as stumped as you are on why that directory name is "magic" for you.

Comment: Two more suggestions -- Try with `wsl --cd "C:\Source\Code\contentmatch.stream" -u root -e bash --noprofile --norc -c pwd` (running as the root user).  If that still gives the same results, try with a different distro/instance entirely, maybe 18.04 or Alpine.  Just something to start a new instance that doesn't have any remnants from your current one.  Then modify the same command again with `wsl -d <distroname> --cd "C:\Source\Code\contentmatch.stream" -e bash --noprofile --norc -c pwd`

Comment: Although I should mention that Alpine is a minimal install that doesn't install `bash` by default, so it would be `wsl -d Alpine --cd "C:\Source\Code\contentmatch.stream" -e sh -c pwd` (insert the correct distro name for Alpine, whatever that is).

Comment: One more (then I need to go cook some chili), `wsl --cd "C:\Source\Code\contentmatch.stream" -e bash --noprofile --norc -c "stat /mnt/c/Source/Code/contentmatch.stream"`

Comment: I have added debian. Set it to default. And all works perfectly fine.
Also:
PS C:\Users\jjk> wsl --cd "C:\Source\Code\contentmatch.stream" -e bash --noprofile --norc -c "stat /mnt/c/Source/Code/contentmatch.stream"
  File: /mnt/c/Source/Code/contentmatch.stream
  Size: 512   Blocks: 0  IO Block: 512    directory
Device: 69h/105d  Inode: 10414574138861192  Links: 1
Access: (0777/drwxrwxrwx)  Uid: ( 1000/  jjk)   Gid: ( 1000/     jjk)
Access: 2021-02-12 22:33:16.805225100 +0100
Modify: 2021-02-12 21:33:12.664140700 +0100
Change: 2021-02-12 21:34:15.903086000 +0100
 Birth: -

Comment: Did the `-u root` make any difference?  We now know that it's something in the Ubuntu instance.  Wondering if it's something specific to the user or to all users.  I would have thought that the `--noprofile --norc` would have normalized that, though.  If `-u root` still has the problem, then I'm thinking maybe something in `/etc`?

Comment: Ah, missed that suggestion, here's that one, same result:
PS C:\Users\jjk> wsl --cd "C:\Source\Code\contentmatch.stream" -u root -e bash --noprofile --norc -c pwd
/root
PS C:\Users\jjk>

Comment: Wow, so here we go. Docker is guilty somehow. I run a grep on the entire WSL firesystem with that dirname, and hundreds of references popped up in "mnt/wsl/docker-desktop-bind-mounts/...". Shut it down just to try, and it fixed that issue. Don't know why.

Comment: Cool - At least you know you're going in the right direction now!  How are your Docker skills?  Apologies if I'm telling you something you already know, but I'm guessing if there are hundreds of references, then there may be containers that have "exited", but haven't been "removed".  I know they tend to pile up for me unless I remember to run them with `--rm` to automatically remove on exit.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WSL open linux shell here doesn't open in the current directory](https://superuser.com/questions/1619781/wsl-open-linux-shell-here-doesnt-open-in-the-current-directory)

Comment: No, the answer has been identified in a chat between myself @NotTheDr01ds but I don't know what happened to the chat log, I thought the link would stay here in the comments. anyway posting the answer now

Comment: Still getting used to chat as well here.  I also would have thought that the chat link would have appeared here since it was suggested automatically.

Answer (score 1):

In this case I have identified that disabling docker made it work. But after restarting it the problem came back.

Upon further search for possible references, the problem went away after wiping clean this directory:
mnt/wsl/docker-desktop-bind-mounts/
Never got to finding the root cause of why the references in that directory were causing this issue.

Comment: Greatest consultation credits got to @NotTheDr01ds